# Dividing Array Index by next Index Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am still learning Java and have a question on an array.

My array:

```
 double arr[] = {1.8, 3.6, 5.0, 2.0};
```

My question is how do I divide the first index by the next and so on, but not the last index.
Each index is to be divided by 2. So that the resulting array looks like this:

```
double arr[] = {0.5, 0.72, 2.5, 2.0};
```

I am on the right track by proceeding this way:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    double arr[] = {1.8, 3.6, 5.0, 2.0};

    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        arr[j] = arr[0] / arr[1];
        arr[j] = arr[1] / arr[2];

        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed and all help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, first try to solve the problem yourself. If you face any problem in implementation, then you can ask the specific problem.

Comment: Hey Rohit, okay I will, its just that I keep hitting a brickwall :[

Comment: Hints: `arr.length` will give you the length: `[0, 1,  ... ,arr.length - 1]` are the indexes of the array. `for` will let you "travel" on the array.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks Maroun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < arr.length-1; j++){
        arr[j] = arr[j] / arr[j+1];
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1]);  // this will print the last element
```

`

Comment: Thats it. I cannot believe how easy you made it look.
Thank you. I know I ask some really basic questions here, but everyone is so helpful, and it is building my own knowledge and experience.
Thank you all.

Comment: sansix i think Op want the result array which contains the output as he mentioned in the post. But solution given  wont print last the last number in source array

Comment: Noted. Yes need to print last index.
Was actually going to do this under the for loop:
    System.out.println(arr[3]);

Comment: @PrimalScientist yeah saw that point. Edited answer would work as per your requirement - you just needed to print `arr[arr.length-1]` after loop for this

Comment: What if I wanted the division to skip index [0] and begin at index [1]. How would I go about this?

Comment: @PrimalScientist from index 1 - if I got u right then do this `for(int j = 1; j < arr.length-1; j++){`

Comment: Will check it out and come back. Thanks Bingo! Cool name by the way.

Comment: @PrimalScientist oh thankx for complement - and yeah feel free to raise questions :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  double arr[] = {1.8, 3.6, 5.0, 2.0};
  int j;
  System.out.print("[");
  for(j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 ; j++) {
    arr[j] = arr[j] / arr[j+1];
    System.out.print(arr[j] + " , ");
  }
  System.out.println(arr[j] + "]");
}
```

As you can see inside the loop, `j` represents the index in each iteration. Your array looks like:

`{1.8, 3.6, 5.0, 2.0}`    `arr.length` is `4`, the indexes are: `0 1 2 3`

```
  ^    ^    ^    ^
  |    |    |    |
  0    1    2    3
```

So we are traveling on the array, dividing each element (`j`) by the next element (`j+1`) and we print it.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes, I can see that now. Thanks for this great feedback.
I have managed to solve it now. Its just getting to understand the way things work. 
This is great for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double arr[] = { 1.8, 3.6, 5.0, 2.0 };
    double[] resultArr = new double[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      double result = arr[i] / arr[i + 1];
      resultArr[i] = result;

    }
    resultArr[arr.length - 1] = arr[arr.length - 1];


  }
```

Comment: Another good way to do this. I am writing it all down!! 
Thank you M Sach!